# Why won't my currency conversion javascript program won't run?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm creating a Javascript program where the user will be asked how much pounds (£) they'd like to convert into Euros. The program should check if the number of pounds is greater than 0 and a number.  If the input is 0 or a negative number or the input is not a number then an error message should be displayed – “input error, please input a number greater than 0”.
If the pounds to be exchanged is > £500 then no commission is charged.  If the number of pounds worked is < = £500 then 3% commission is charged.
An output message should be displayed to show the number of euros exchanged.

P.s Amateur js programmer

```
const exchange = 1.19;
var pounds = 0;
var euros = 0.0;

pounds = prompt("Enter the amount of pounds you wish to convert": );

if (pounds <= 0) {
  error_message = ("Input error! Please input a number greater than 0!");
} else if (pounds > 500) {
  euros = (pounds * exchange);
  alert(euros);
} else {
  euros = (pounds * exchange);
  euros = (euros - ((euros / 100) * 3));
  alert(euros);
}
```

Comment: Hey Bobby, welcome to Stack Overflow. Since you're new here, it's a good idea to check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. So your question is useful to others with the same problem, you should describe the specific problem in the title, and also include what output your program does produce (including error messages if that's what you're getting). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything what you get from the `prompt` is `string`.
You can parse your `pound` into the number with `parseInt` or `parseFloat` functions.

```js
const exchange = 1.19;
var euros = 0.0;

var text = prompt("Enter the amount of pounds you wish to convert: ");
const pounds = parseFloat(text);

if (pounds <= 0) {
  error_message = ("Input error! Please input a number greater than 0!");
} else if (pounds > 500) {
  euros = pounds * exchange;
  alert(euros);
} else {
  euros = (pounds * exchange);
  euros = (euros - ((euros / 100) * 3));
  alert(euros);
}
```

Comment: you can use "+" operator to cast to int

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón you are right. I like to use functions instead of `+` sign, because for newer programmer the function is more understandable than `+` sign

Comment: i know  its only rockandroll but i like it, sampling rolling stones ;)

Answer (score 0):

The prompt is a string, as it returns a string (even though ou desire a number)

To convert it, use the `Number` constructor (or function)

try this:

```
pounds = prompt("Enter the amount of pounds you wish to convert");
pounds = Number(pounds);
```

or, you could cast it using the `+` sign

```
pounds = +pounds;
```